# How to append specific Word to each column using Dynamic Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

From a temp table I populate from the sys schema, I want to assemble a Dynamic SQL query that appends the word `PriorYear` to each column alias.

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
DECLARE @SQLSTR nvarchar(max); 

SET @SQLSTR = 'SELECT' 
FOR EACH TABLEITEM IN #temptbllist
    FOR EACH COLUMNITEM IN  #tempschema WHERE table_name =  TABLEITEM

    SET @SQLSTR  COLUMNITEM ' as PriorYear' +  COLUMNITEM

    ENDFOR
    SET @SQLSTR 'FROM ' + TABLEITEM ';'
ENDFOR
```

Starting with this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempschema
(
schema_name     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
table_name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
column_name     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO  #tempschema
VALUES 
(   'TestSchema',   'Employee', 'ID'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Employee', 'FirstName'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Employee', 'LastName'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Employee', 'Rank'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Employee', 'Salary'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Facility', 'ID'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Facility', 'FacilityName'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Facility', 'County'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Facility', 'State'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Facility', 'ZipCode'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Manager',  'EmployeeID'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Manager',  'Department'),
(   'TestSchema',   'Manager',  'YearStarted');
        
CREATE TABLE #temptbllist
(
tblname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO   #temptbllist
VALUES 
('Facility');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just use two nested `STRING_AGG` aggregations.

I *strongly* suggest you also use `QUOTENAME` to quote the columns and tables correctly.

```sql
DECLARE @SQLSTR nvarchar(max); 

SELECT @SQLSTR =
  STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT
',
      ts.columns,
      '
FROM ',
      QUOTENAME(ts.schema_name),
      '.',
      QUOTENAME(ts.table_name),
      ';'
    ),
    '
' )
FROM #temptbllist tt
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      ts.schema_name,
      ts.table_name,
      columns = STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME(ts.column_name) + N' as ' + QUOTENAME(N'PriorYear' + ts.column_name) AS nvarchar(max)), ', ')
    FROM #tempschema ts
    WHERE ts.table_name = tt.tblname
    GROUP BY
      ts.schema_name,
      ts.table_name
) ts;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/xf2GFnMU)